# Spark fails to read local s3 with localstack >=2.x

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, localstack

I am trying to write an end-to-end test for a spark job reading data from s3.
I used localstack to start local s3 and configured boto3 and spark session with the localstack endpoint.

Whenever I use localstack version up to `1.4.0` it all works fine, but **as soon as I update to a `2.x` version (lastest is `2.1.0`) boto3 calls still work just fine, but spark fails saying that the bucket does not exist**.

I have tried different versions of spark (`3.2.1` - `3.4.0`) and behavior is the same.

install dependencies

```
pip3 install pyspark==3.2.1 localstack==2.1.0 boto3
```

start locastack:

```
IMAGE_NAME=localstack/localstack:2.1.0 localstack start --detached
```

Run example spark code:

```
import boto3
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

s3 = boto3.resource("s3", endpoint_url="http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566")

bucket = s3.Bucket("foo-bucket")

if bucket in s3.buckets.all():
    bucket.objects.delete()
    bucket.delete()

bucket.create(CreateBucketConfiguration={"LocationConstraint": "eu-central-1"})
print(f"Boto3 list buckets: {list(s3.buckets.all())}")

bucket.put_object(Key="foo-csv/data.csv", Body="1,2,3")
print(f"Boto3 list objects: {list(bucket.objects.all())}")

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.endpoint", "http://localhost.localstack.cloud:4566") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key", "DUMMY") \
    .config("spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key", "DUMMY") \
    .config("spark.jars.packages","org.apache.spark:spark-hadoop-cloud_2.12:3.2.1") \
    .getOrCreate()

try:
    df = spark.read.csv("s3a://foo-bucket/foo-csv")
    df.show()
except Exception as e:
    print("error reading CSV")
    print(e)

try:
    spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3)], schema="c1 int, c2 int, c3 int").write.parquet("s3a://foo-bucket/foo-parquet")
    print("Wrote parquet")
except Exception as e:
    print("error writing parquet")
    print(e)
```

renders error:

```
error reading CSV
[PATH_NOT_FOUND] Path does not exist: s3a://foo-bucket/foo-csv.
error writing parquet
[...]
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: The specified bucket does not exist
```

---

If I use the `1.4.0` version of the localstack image the above code runs just fine reading csv and writing parquet:

```
IMAGE_NAME=localstack/localstack:1.4.0 localstack start --detached
```

check the local bucket's contents:

```
awslocal s3 ls foo-bucket --recursive
2023-06-10 12:52:01          5 foo-csv/data.csv
2023-06-10 12:52:26          0 foo-parquet/_SUCCESS
2023-06-10 12:52:25        446 foo-parquet/part-00000-522f007c-6233-4097-a07c-67caf1925906-c000.snappy.parquet
2023-06-10 12:52:26        890 foo-parquet/part-00007-522f007c-6233-4097-a07c-67caf1925906-c000.snappy.parquet
```

Comment: 1. maybe a bug in localstack, in which case: take it up with them.
2. before that you should explicitly set the s3a connector to use path style access (not virtual hostnames) and http. Look at the hadoop s3a docs for these.

Comment: Hi stevel, 
thanks for the answer - setting the `spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true` did solve my problem. This way I can also just use `http://localhost:4566` as an entrypoint without the magic localstack host. Feel free to write an answer and I will grant you the bounty I offered 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3A connector/AWS client uses AWS virtual hostnames, so generates a hostname "foo-bucket.localhost.localstack.cloud" to talk to. Why is that the default? can help with load balancing on real S3.

For private S3 stores, unless you have DNS and your HTTPS certificates set up, you need to switch to "path style access" which builds up the operations as paths under the endpoint URL

```
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.path.style.access=true
```

Comment: Thanks - this solves my problem. The question is still open why it worked in localstack `1.4.0` without this property set. I suspect some docker networking.